# Possible to create a column that users can upload an image to?

Tags: list, column, image

I'm trying to create a column in a list that users can upload a picture to.  I found the `Hyperlink or Picture`, but this requires that users specify a URL for the image.

Is there way to create a column that will allow users to upload an image from their hard drive  rather than specify a URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you provision a Picture Library as a starting point and then customize that? That would give you a list with the built-in behaviour of an OOB picture library, rather than starting from a normal list.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I can think of.  I would think that with some client side code, you could simulate that functionality by presenting the user an browse/upload screen that dumps the file into a picture/document library, gets the URL and places it back into the hyperlink field.

Answer (score 1):

Check this open source solution:
http://sparqubepicturelite.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Telerik Rad Editor (Lite) along with a Rich Text field and have the user embed the picture that way.  Should work but you are making a blanket change on how your users interact with Rich Text Fields.